# Is there a way to prepopulate fields (card number, expiration data, cvv) in react-native-square-in-app-payments to get nonce?

Tags: javascript, react-native, square

I'm building an app with react-native and my flow is to scan card -> `payment but react-native-square-in-app-payments` requires it's own ui which needs to be filled to get the nonce.

Is there a way to pre-populate the fields in the ui from the info scanned from card?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to pre-populate the fields at this time. You will need to manually type in the card information. Note that you can save the card after the first time, if you choose. See the [Save Cards on File Cookbook](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/customers-api/cookbook/save-cards-on-file) in the Square documentation (and you will then probably be interested in the [Charge Cards on File Cookbook](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/customers-api/cookbook/charge-cards-on-file)).